# Ошибка сертификата у META

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, ssl, сертификат

Необходимо срочно проверить настройку сервера.

Судя по ответу Chrome:

> Не удалось подтвердить, что это сервер meta.ru.stackoverflow.com.
>   Его сертификат безопасности относится к *.stackexchange.com.
>   Возможно, сервер настроен неправильно или кто-то пытается перехватить ваши данные.

Сертификат не от того сервера используется.

Comment: В чате вроде уже я поднимал эту тему.
Ограничение на количество доменов вроде.

Comment: Не понял немного про ограничение количества доменов.

Comment: Вроде в сертификате не указана русская мета. По другой версии домен 4-го уровня - перебор.

Comment: Мета - домен четвертого уровня. Сертификат распространяется только на *.stackoverflow.com, *.stackexchange.com (и некоторые другие - можно посмотреть в описании сертификата в Subject Alternative Name). Для меты в частности надо чтоб был wildcard `*.*.stackoverflow.com`. Аналогичное сообщение можно увидеть на любой мете, любого сообщества. / В любом случае зеленый адресбар ожидать на любой странице SO не стоит, т.к. куча контента идет с cdn по http... Это глобальная проблема.

Comment: В любом случае это баг, и его надо починить.